# How to call AlertIOS in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I am an iOS developer, but I know a little javascript. I am trying to use the AlertIOS, the document api is this

```
static alert(title: string, message?: string, buttons?: Array<{ text: ?string; onPress: ?Function; }>)
```

I am confused with the parameters. I tried to write like this,but it give me error.
AlertIOS('Username empty', 'Please type your username', buttons: {{text: 'Cancel', onPress: onPressCancel}});

How can i use **AlertIOS** properly ?

Comment: Can you post the error message? Thanks!

Comment: @KevinChen Can you tell me did I write the call correctly?

Answer (score 4):

If you look at [the documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alertios.html#content), it's says that there's an `AlertIOS` API with a static method called `alert`. That means you can call it like this:

```
AlertIOS.alert('Username empty', 'Please type your username', [{text: 'Cancel', onPress: onPressCancel}]);
```

Notice that you also don't need the "buttons:" prefix for the buttons array - that part of your call wasn't valid syntax anyway.

The method signature for alert is documented using [Flow](http://flowtype.org/) type annotations. Each argument is described like this:

- name of argument: type of argument

And if the name has a question mark, that argument is optional. So, in this case the arguments are:

- title, with a type of string
- message, with a type of string (optional)
- buttons, with a type of array (optional)

You'll also need to make sure you `require` the AlertIOS API, probably something like this:

```
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  AlertIOS
} = React;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Remember to add "**AlertIOS**" into your React requires list